# Meteor Methods on console

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods, server, console.log

Is there any way to console all the server method names that are called from client with their calling counts?

Like Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions shows all subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Meteor.call with a function that will do the logging. The article shows [how to create a wrapper function](https://blog.getsentry.com/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions.html).

```
const call = Meteor.call;
Meteor.call = function() {
  // call the db incrementing the call count.
  return call(this, ...arguments);
}
```